# Google login not working in IONIC Mobile application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm facing issue of google login in ionic mobile application.

Though before uploading on google play console it's working fine and once i upload on the google play console for testting purpose it's not working properly.

Let me know if any one have any idea on this why this missbehaving.

thanks in advance

Comment: When you upload the app on google play for testing purpose, I think the 'App signing key certificate' will change. Check to see if the MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are corresponding.

Comment: okay will look in it, but one week back i upload the release version and this same happen again login is not working google accounts popup is coming and another popup the permissions one is not coming any comment on this ?@Callan

Comment: What kind of errors do you get in the logs? When you run the app in simulator/real device connected to your machine, you should see some logs/ error messages in Android Studio. Can you check pls?

Comment: no it's working fine on my device what i have problem is when i upload the same application on google play console and from where i'm downloading the application as internal tester then google login is not working properly